# Is there a way to declare a Spatial Index with EntityFrameworkCore 2.2?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, sqlgeography, nettopologysuite

I am using **Entity Framework Core 2.2** with **NetTopologySuite 1.15.1** and **SQL Server 2016**. Having a column of type `IPoint` works great to the point I want to create an index on it.

I have this table

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IPoint Coordinates { get; set; }

    public static void Register(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>(entity => entity.HasIndex(x => new {x.Coordinates}));
    }
}
```

And EF core handles it well while generating a migration thus producing the following code:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Locations_Coordinates",
    schema: "data",
    table: "Locations",
    column: "Coordinates");
```

However, as soon as I try to apply the migration to database, `SqlException` is thrown with the following message

> SqlException: Column 'Coordinates' in table 'data.Locations' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index or statistics.

SQL Server *does* support indexes on columns of type `geography`.

I believe the reason might be that EF Core is trying to create a [regular index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) rather than [spatial one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-spatial-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Am I doing something wrong or it's just not supported? Is there a way to tell EF Core that it should create spatial index?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the issues log for EF Core it appears that creating Spatial Indexes isn't yet supported.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12538

[image: github]

Issue [1100](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1100) is support Spatial Data Types on SQL Server and SQL Lite.